# Youtube/Instagram comments style in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to achieve a Youtube/Instagram-like comment style in my iOS app, or more specifically - a label that has the username at the beggining of the label with a different color and the rest of the content afterwards, and the content can drop lines beneath the username. For example:

```
USERNAME(with different color)  this is the comment content,
and it can drop lines like that.
```

I have managed to achieve that using `NSMutableAttributedString`, but since my app supports multiple languages with different writing directions it glitches quite badly.
How can I achieve this style in a `UILabel`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try two different labels.

or you can use following code

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString: label.attributedText];

[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                   value:[UIColor redColor] 
                   range:NSMakeRange(0, /*userNameLength*/)];

[label setAttributedText:text];
```

Comment: You can create two diff. UILabel each one for userName (diff. color and font style) and for comment string.

Comment: Yes but then I won't be able to get the effect I showed in the example.

Answer (score 0):

set an `NSAttributedString` to the `UILabel`

you can set specific fonts / colours etc to a particular range of characters within the `NSAttributedString`

Comment: As I've mentioned, I did try that but since my app supports different languages and different writing directions this method glitches.

Comment: it won't glitch if you implement it properly - just need more details about this 'glitching'

Comment: If I set my label alignment to be left to right for example, in English it would like fine, like that: `USERNAME  content content` but in a right to left language that would look like `content content USERNAME`, which looks very wrong. I need it to be unified.